# What do I replace IQueryable with for Async operations?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have a `Projects` table in my DB with multiple relationships. Various different queries in the DB layer of my c# code would be interested in joining this table with different others. So I abstracted away the following:

```
public IQueryable<Project> QueryProject(Project prj)
{
    return Context.Projects.Where(p => p.id == prj.id);
}
```

... so I can reuse this method in various other scenarios, such as...

```
_queryService.QueryProject(prj).Include(p => p.Users)
```

... or

```
_queryService.QueryProject(prj).Include(p => p.Artefacts)
```

... etc. At one point, I decide that making action methods asynchronous is a good idea, so I try the following:

```
await _queryService.QueryProject(prj).Include(p => p.Artefacts).SingleAsync();
```

However, the moment I try to make any operation using the `QueryProject` method asynchronous, I get the following error from my unit tests:

> The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

So clearly I shouldn't be using IQueryable as a return type for my first `QueryProject` abstraction. However, I'm struggling to find a viable alternative. I do NOT want any DB retrieval of entities during the execution of `QueryProject`. I'm also not interested in hacks that simply hide this error without bringing me any benefit. I'm only trying to abstract away repeating code.

Is some type of alternative supported in .NET core 2.1?

P.S. [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) raised a valid concern, that the problem could be in my unit tests. Here's my mocking code for reference (using Moq):

```
mockServices.Setup(x => x.QueryProject(It.IsAny<SomeProjectAbstraction>()))
    .Returns(new List<Project>
    {
        new Project
        {
            Name = ...
        }
    }.AsQueryable());
```

Comment: Does the code work when you use code inside QueryProject directly?

Comment: "*I get the following error from my **unit tests**"* Then most likely the issue is not caused by EF Core, but your unit tests mocks or whatever you use there (except a real EF Core `IQueryable<T>`).

Comment: Thank you @Euphoric and Ivan Stoev - the problem has to do with the way I mock variables. With this observation it was easy to find an already existing answer, so I'd mark my own question as a duplicate (or delete it)...

Answer (score 1):

`IQueryable<T>` is a construct that enables you to build up queries *before* they are handled by the database. There's nothing async about any of that. The part where async gets involved is when you actually send the query to your database and wait for the response (which is what is happening when you use `SingleAsync()`). At that point, you no longer have an `IQueryable<T>`, because now it's an actual result set.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything about why the OP is getting the error that they're getting or how to correct it.  The question demonstrates that they understand that `IQueryable<T>` is used for building a query, not executing it, given that they asked how to do what they're asking without materializing the results of the query.